# How can I resolve a situation in which my Mac keeps crashing while working with a specific video file?

Tags: video, crash, kernel-panic, video-editing, final-cut-pro

My MacBook Pro 2016 with Touch Bar keeps having a kernel panic whenever I attempt to use a specific video file I recorded with my Atomos Shogun Flame. FCPX imports and uses all of the other files from the same shoot fine. However, if I try to play, create a proxy, or do anything that involves handling this file after import, my computer reboots.

So far I've attempted to re-encode the file using Adobe Media Encoder, but FCPX still has issues with it. I've tried importing the file into Adobe Premiere but the system still crashes (i.e. it freezes, turns off, then reboots). If I put my SSD back in the Atomos Shogun, and watch the entire file, it plays perfectly fine.

I've also attempted transferring the file from the SSD to my internal drive, as well as to my RAID prior to importing it, but that causes the same issue.

**Is there a tool that I can use to fix this file so my computer won't crash while using it? Or is there something else I can try to get around this issue?**

The Shogun Flame has limited file management capabilities, so I am unable to do anything on that end. I haven't purchased Apple Compressor, so Adobe Media Encoder is the primary tool I have to convert files.

Comment: When you say *"I've tried importing the file into premiere but the system still crashes"*, what do you mean? Are you saying the MBP itself crashes, that Adobe Premiere crashes, or that after trying to use it with FCP that FCP crashes?

Comment: @Monomeeth the MBP crashes, just as it did while trying to use the file in FCPX.

Comment: Okay, so when you say the MBP crashes, what does this mean? Are you saying it freezes up? It reboots? You get the spinning beachball? And, are you saying this happens when trying to use the video with Adobe Premiere after the import, or is it happening during the import process?

Comment: @Monomeeth the MBP freezes, turns off, then reboots. It seems to happen at some stage during the import process.

Comment: @Buscar웃 someone? Like a person?

Comment: @Buscar웃 there are a couple things that show SIGKILL, but none of them are relevant to FCPX or Premiere. I don't believe SIGKILL would cause the computer to freeze and reboot every time I am playing with the same file.

Comment: @Buscar웃 um... ok thanks? I don't see how DriveFileStream (none of the files are stored there) or a few other preference things (no FCPX or Premiere) sending SIGKILL at times not associated with the multiple kernel panics I've had are related. The only thing that is a constant is this video file. Which is why I am attempting to find a tool to actually repair the video file, so I can use it.

Comment: I've posted an answer as a starting point, but will add more if other tings come to mind. Also, it'd be good if you could edit your question to include any of the additional things we've clarified via the comments.

Answer (score 1):

No-one here is going to be able to give you a 100% definitive answer on why a specific video file is causing a crash (especially without full details of the file in question and without access to it), except of course to say it's most likely corrupted in some way.

Some things to try include:

- Booting your MBP into Safe Mode and trying to import the file again.
- I know you've tried re-encoding the file using Adobe Media Encoder, but perhaps you could try encoding the file into a totally different format first. Ideally you would try doing this within the Atomos Shogun Flame directly, but I'm not familiar with that device and don't know what export/editing functions it has. If none, have you got any other software to try converting it?
- Another thing to try would be to manually copy the file from the SD card onto another card/drive (or to your Mac) without going through an import process. If that succeeds, then try importing the file (or converting it into a new format) from the new location.
- Open the file using Quicktime Player and, assuming it opens okay, use Quicktime's export function to export it (with a new filename). Then see if the newly exported file can be imported into FCP and edited fine.
- Take a look at your FCP preferences to see if changing how it deals with situations like dropped frames will make a difference.

Comment: I have attempted transferring the file from the SSD to my internal drive, as well as to my RAID prior to importing it, but that causes the same issue. The Shogun Flame has limited file management capabilities, so I am unable to do anything on that end. AME is the primary tool I have to convert files, I've not purchased Compressor. I'll try a couple of your other troubleshooting ideas and report back if any work.

Comment: No worries. Please also report back if they don't work, and also edit your Question to include these additional details (incl. things you've tried). That's the best way to hopefully get an answer from someone that will help you. :)

Comment: Converting the file to an h.264 file seems to do the trick, which makes me wonder why I can't re-encode the file to the same format as the source. If all the data is there to create the h.264 version, why is the ProRes 42 version not working?

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer, no-one here can give you a definite answer on this. But, now that you seem to have a working copy, my next step would be to make a copy of that and then try to convert *that* version to ProRes 42 just to see what happens. Also, it may be worth using a different SD card in the Atomos Shogun Flame, or reformatting the SD card (just in case the problem was caused by that).

Comment: The Solid State Drive is reformatted prior to each shoot. Once a file is converted to h.264 it becomes compressed, so there's not really a true way to convert h.264 to ProRes 422 HQ. There may actually be a different factor at play. I've discovered that if I have the library on my internal SSD as opposed to my external ThunderBolt RAID, then FCPX doesn't crash while working with this file. So there's some combination of weirdness going on.

Comment: Interestingly I'm having an issue with a completely different file now that I imported via FCPX. Once I read a specific part of the file my whole system crashes. I've also attempted to copy the file off of my external RAID and converting it with AME, but no solution has word yet :(